# How can I install Elementary OS Freya 3.2 64bit on mac mini 1.1 flashed to 2.1?

Tags: release-freya, system-installation, boot, 64-bit, macintosh

How can I install Elementary OS Freya 0.3.2 64Bit on mac mini 1.1 flashed to 2.1?
I have flashed mac mini 1.1 (to 2.1 EFI) with 4GB RAM, 128GB SSD, DVD-RW, upgraded CPU to 64bit (intel C2D t7200).
However I can not install 64bit Freya to it.
Is there a ISO image amd64+maclike ubuntu does, quote:
"These disks have explicitly removed EFI bootable binaries forcing a machine to boot with BIOS compatibility."

Please help,
P.

Comment: I guess mac mini 1.1 and mac mini 2.1 has EFI32 (32bit), so I can not install 64bit eOS. :(

Answer (score 1):

The Mac Mini 1.1 was a Core duo, not a Core 2 Duo, and 32-bit only. It might work with a 32 bit version, but I'm guessing that the slight difference in the architecture might be the problem. From memory, that model Mac Mini didn't have a soldered processor, so you could take out the core 2 and put in a core 2 duo chip instead (check for compatibility first). It would still be 32 bit, though.

Answer (score 0):

This site has instruction on removing EFI from linux instal ISOs and some sample ISO's.
https://mattgadient.com/2016/07/11/linux-dvd-images-and-how-to-for-32-bit-efi-macs-late-2006-models/

I was able to install Mint with no issue. I want to try elementary soon.